# Pure WebRTC vs VLine. Why WebRTC has more noises than VLine?

Tags: webrtc, vline

I tried to use pure WebRTC. But it has huge noises. I tested with Linux PC and Android device.

So my question is what does VLine use to decrease noises?

Comment: I think this is not the place to ask this kind of question (it is not related to a programming problem...)

Comment: Looks like they use googEchoCancellation parameters in their SDP creation and adjust them